# json = null in fromJSON method in custom JsonConverter " freezed class with multiple constructors "

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed

I have this class

```
@freezed
abstract class CartEntity with _$CartEntity {
  const factory CartEntity.empty(String status, String message) = _Empty;

  const factory CartEntity.notEmpty(int x) = _NotEmpty;

  factory CartEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CartEntityFromJson(json);

}
```

And this converter

```
class CartEntityConverter
    implements JsonConverter<CartEntity, Map<String, dynamic>> {
  const CartEntityConverter();

  @override
  CartEntity fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    //the problem here
    print(json);// null 

    return _Empty.fromJson(json);

  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(CartEntity object) {
    return object.toJson();
  }
}
```

And this wrapper class

```
@freezed
abstract class CartEntityWrapper with _$CartEntityWrapper {
  const factory CartEntityWrapper(@CartEntityConverter() CartEntity cartEntity) =
      CartEntityWrapperData;

  factory CartEntityWrapper.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CartEntityWrapperFromJson(json);
}
```

And iam called

```
    final cartEntity = CartEntityWrapperData.fromJson({'x':'y'});
    print(cartEntity);
```

fromJson method which in CartEntityConverter is always receive null json so  what's i made wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by using

```
    final cartEntity = CartEntityConverter().fromJson({'x':'y'});
    print(cartEntity);
```

instead of

```
    final cartEntity = CartEntityWrapperData.fromJson({'x':'y'});
    print(cartEntity);
```

documentation have a lack at this point i tried random stuffs to make it work

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making yet another converter class that you use directly, you could just add `.fromJsonA` method in the main class.

It will looks like this one:

```dart
@freezed
abstract class CartEntity with _$CartEntity {
  const factory CartEntity.empty(String status, String message) = _Empty;

  const factory CartEntity.notEmpty(int x) = _NotEmpty;

factory CartEntity.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CartEntityFromJson(json);

  factory CartEntity.fromJsonA(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

if (/*condition for .empty constructor*/) {
      return _Empty.fromJson(json);
    } else if (/*condition for .notEmpty constructor*/) {
      return _NotEmpty.fromJson(json);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Could not determine the constructor for mapping from JSON');

    }
}

}
```

Comment: I'll try this way .. Thanks <3